# Do we need to stop NiFi when we dynamically update existing WorkFlow?

Tags: apache-nifi

In my existing NiFi workflow I have following scenerio:
1) I may have to add new Kafka Topic dynamically.
2) I may have to add new route.
3) I may need to add new processor (not sure whether on the flow we can add new processor!)

My question is if my NiFi workflow is running in production do I need to stop and restart it when I dynamically (on the fly) update the workflow?

In what scenario, I need to bring it down? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to restart the whole NiFi instance, but some changes may required stopping and starting a specific processor. For example, if you have a ConsumeKafka processor with a list of topics, you would have to stop it, add the new topic to the property, and start it again. You could script these operations using the REST API.